GLMMs with crossed random effects: How do I quantify the reduction in random effects variance of including fixed effects? Or, indeed, should I?
I am modelling test score outcomes (0/1) using a GLMM with crossed random effects for persons and items. As I add significant fixed effects estimates for person and item, the variance estimate for the relevant random effect reduces, as illustrated.
A.  Null model: 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 3.268    1.808   
 item   (Intercept) 2.612    1.616   


B.  Model including fixed effect for persons: 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 1.752    1.323   
 item   (Intercept) 2.604    1.614   


C.  Model including fixed effect (1) for items: 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 1.751    1.323   
 item   (Intercept) 2.158    1.469   


D.  Model including fixed effect (2) for items: 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 1.751    1.323   
 item   (Intercept) 1.874    1.369   


In accounting for the systematicities in the responses for either persons or items, as I understand it, the random variance is accordingly reduced. I am wondering if there is a metric that will help me quantify this? Is it reasonable to express the reduced variance estimate as a proportion compared the null model estimate? I realise however that the impact is not exclusive, i.e. the person fixed effect clearly has some impact on reducing the item random variance in this case.
Pseudo R2 estimates give information about the role of fixed effects in explaining the overall outcome, however I am particularly interested in the relationship between the item fixed effects and the item random variance, which doesn’t seem to be covered by these statistics.
Am I missing something obvious? Of course, I can explore similar questions using other analytic methods (e.g., MIRT), but for the current analysis it would be very helpful for me to be able to assess this within the GLMM framework. Or is this not a realistic undertaking? I am not finding any examples in my searches in which this is presented as an option.
Many thanks in advance.
